# How can i initialize inputStream in constructor and count the words passed in it

Tags: java

I'm trying to solve a homework exercise that wants me to count the term frequency in a given inputStream remove duplicates etc... I have an idea how to do the rest of the methods that asks me to but I'm not sure if i initialize the InputStream correctly and how can i count the words in it. It also gives us a hint that we can use sets/maps. Do you have any idea on why and where? I only need few hints regarding the inputStream since I'm pretty new to it.

```
package com.example.mfromtheleaf;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {

    class TermFrequency {
        private String[] stopWords;
        private InputStream is;
        private Set<String> words;


        public TermFrequency(String[] stopWords, InputStream is) {
            this.stopWords = stopWords;
            this.is = is;
        }

        public int countTotal() {
            int count = 0;

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Google for Java IO tutorial, and read. But since it's homework, I guess your teacher must also have talked about that before. Read your notes.

Comment: What have you tried? In general people will be more willing to help if you demonstrate that you have given it a good attempt yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.make a `Map` to store the word and word frequency,the key of `Map` is your input words,every value will be set to 0.

2.use `BufferedReader` read your `InputStream` one line by one line,then spilit the line to `String[]`,traverse the array and go to the map find the word is exist or not.if exist,then the frequency puls one.

code like this:

```
        String[] terms = new String[2];
        Map<String, Integer> map = Arrays.asList(terms).stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e, e -> Integer.parseInt("0")));
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(""));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String lineContent = null;
        while (null != (lineContent = reader.readLine())) {
            String[] words = lineContent.split(" ");
            Arrays.asList(words).stream()
                .forEach(s -> {
                    Integer counts = map.get(s);
                    if (null != counts) {
                        counts++;
                    }
                });
        }
```